# Go to a page with an internal hyperlink to a video stream

Tags: javascript

When you go on a page and you click on something that calls up a javascript (like sections on Wikipedia that generate the '#...' in the URL) the URL changes in the address bar of your browser.

On Wikipedia, I can just use a link the includes the #... to go to a specific section. However, in other cases, it doesn't work, for example http://local.filmon.com/#ITV1 will just redirect to http:// local.filmon.com/#LIVE-BOXING.

I don't know anything about these things so I'm sorry if I was vague. I just want to know if by any means, in the latter example, it is possible to go to the page http://local.filmon.com and load the ITV1 channel without having to actually click on it on the left-hand side.

edit: In the case of the video I want (the ITV1 from filmon), when I inspect element in Firefox I find:

```
<strong class="channels_search_title" style="text-overflow: ellipsis; max-height: 30px;">
 <a class="fake" alt="ITV1 " href="javascript:void(0);">
    ITV1 
 </a>
</strong>
```

But I can't use javascript:void(0) as an internal hyperlink I assume, so I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are referring to is actually known as "Internal Hyperlinking".
There's no JavaScript involved here.

> An internal link is a hyperlink that is a reference or navigation
>   element in a document to another section of the same document or to
>   another document that may be on or part of the same website or domain
>   of the internet. In articles like this one, the words highlighted in
>   blue are examples of internal links.

In short, you are able to access the specific section directly because id of the tag is same as the one you are entering after '#'.

Reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_link

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_anchor

---

You are accessing the section of the page using its id only. Let's consider example of:
`http://www.xbox.com/en-IN/index#CopyrightLogo`

When you click this link, the browser will scroll down to the bottom automatically to bring Microsoft Logo into frame.

Here, 'CopyrightLogo' is the id of the Microsoft Logo you can see at the bottom right corner of the page. You can check the id by:

- Internet Explorer: Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> on key board & then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and then click Microsoft Logo in the bottom right corner. It'll show you the id of the logo as 'CopyrightLogo'
  [image]
- Google Chrome: Right click on Microsoft Logo in the bottom right corner & select `Inspect element`
  will give you the id of the logo as 'CopyrightLogo'

---

Finally, I found is http://www.filmon.com/#ITV%2B1 the link you want to access. I was unable to find http://www.filmon.com/#ITV1. The nearest match is `ITV+1` whose html representation is `ITV%2B1`.

Comment: I see thanks! But then why can't I access the link in my second example?

Comment: @user226995: You cannot access the link in your second example because there's no internal link available for the link you want to access. 

See, every element on a page has a unique id. The id of the link you are accessing may not be 'ITV1', instead it may be 'Interactive-TV-1' (or whatever it's id is).

I wasn't able to find anything like ITV1. Other examples include:

Comment: Can you quote an example from wikipedia?

Comment: I see... Here is an example on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-saxons#History

Comment: Exactly, what I wanted. Well, it really is a new thing for me too… :)
But the concept remains the same. You are accessing that section of the page using the id of the element only.

I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Alright, I inspected the element, but still no luck! I edited my question.

Comment: @user226995: I will resolve your query by 15.30 GMT. I cannot access 'Video' sites in my office.

Comment: The address was rather local.filmon.com, but it really doesn't matter which channel. But does this link actually show the ITV+1 channel when you use it? For me it still redirects to #LIVE-BOXING.

Comment: Yeah… when i clicked on it, it showed me http://www.filmon.com/#ITV%2B1 where `%2B` is the percent encoded code for `+`.
Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Alrgith, I'll take it from here. Thanks a lot for your time and help!!

Comment: Pleasure is mine. I too learnt new things out of it!!! :)